# Are there any jquery conflicts in my wordpress code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, checkbox, content-management-system

I have a wordpress page, where I would like to check a category in the checkbox by using the data-value. In this case "Announcement"

This script works on codepen just fine, but not on wordpress. The following is everything I put on the wordpress page.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var input = $('input[data-value="Announcement"]')
  input.focus();
  input.select();
  input.prop('checked', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<input type="checkbox" id="test" name="category[]" data-wpt-type="checkbox" data-wpt- id="test" data-wpt- name="category[]" value="1" data-parent="-1" data-value="Announcement" class="wpt-form-checkbox form-checkbox checkbox">

<input type="checkbox" id="test2" name="category[]" data-wpt-type="checkbox" data-wpt- id="test2" data-wpt- name="category[]" value="2" data-parent="-1" data-value="Story" class="wpt-form-checkbox form-checkbox checkbox">
```

Is this a jquery issue/conflict? A theme conflict, or wrong code?

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: 
b(...).not(...).filter(...).mediaelementplayer is not a function 
a@http://localhost/wordpress2018/wp-includes/js/mediaelement/wp- 
mediaelement.min.js?ver=4.9.8:1:634 g/</k<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js:2: 
30262
 undefined jquery.min.js:2:31515
jQuery.Deferred exception: jQuery(...).css(...).mCustomScrollbar is 
not a 
function Init_BodyConv@http://localhost/wordpress2018/wp- 
content/plugins/um-messaging/assets/js/um-messaging.js?ver=4.9.8:36:2
@http://localhost/wordpress2018/wp-content/plugins/um- 
messaging/assets/js/um-messaging.js?ver=4.9.8:115:2 j@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js:2:2994 g/</k<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js:2:30262
```

Comment: Check the console for errors. Also note that you only need the `prop()` line to set the checked state.

Comment: I added some of the console errors that I feel are relevant, I am still a noob, is there something in there that points to the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress themes typically use [jQuery.noConflict()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) which makes global `$` undefined to prevent conflicts with other libraries that may also use `$`

Try changing

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
```

To

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                             // ^^
```

which will expose `$` inside the `ready` callback

Comment: suggesting an edit: `which makes global $ undefined to prevent conflicts with other libraries` -> `which makes global $ undefined to drive developers crazy`.

Comment: So what errors are thrown in browser dev tools console?

Comment: try adding `$ = jQuery;` as the first line in your function. Crazy, but often solves it for me!

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to remove jquery CDN
2. Download jquery.min.js manually
3. Instead of enqueing the related jquery/js file from function.php, include in the head like `<script src="<?php echo get_bloginfo( 'template_directory' ); ?>/js/jquery.min.js"></script>`
4. Then include the js file that gives function not found below jquery include

This solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to re-install or upgrade wordpress installation, it helped me with this mediaelementplayer.js errors